# Npm, EventEmitter memory leak

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

When I install nomething via Npm, it shows me this warning
`(node:9936) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit (Use` node --trace-warnings ... `to show where the warning was created)`

npm version **9.8.1**
Node version **20.4.0**

I am thinking about how to solve this warning

Comment: same here. Even with empty code (just single console.out(...) and no matter what package is being installed, this message pops up.

Comment: Any solutions here?

Comment: lts versions did not have such a problem